# Objective C - Core data and NSFetchedResultController?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

So I have a fetched result controller that returns a list of objects.
I am trying to detect any changes to the object including changes to sub objects

Object has these properties `(NSString myString, NSSNumber myNumber, Object2 myObject2)`

so any changes to `myString`, and `myNumber` would cause the FetchedResultController to notify the delegate. But changes to `myObject2` properties won't trigger the fetchedResultController to call the delegate.

Am i doing anything wrong? Am i suppose to manually let myObject know that it has to notify the fetchedResultController?

Comment: When you say "changes to `myObject2` properties", do you mean that you've made changes to the object and you have saved the managed object context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the answer:

implement the following methods in child class (myObject2), and on every keyValue changes notify the owner class

```
- (void)willChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
   [super willChangeValueForKey:key];
   [self.myMainObject willChangeValueForKey:@"myObject2"];
}

- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
   [super didChangeValueForKey:key];
   [self.myMainObject didChangeValueForKey:@"myObject2"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you "change" `myString` and your NSFetchedResultsController (NSFRC) responds with its event, you need to realize what is actually occurring.

The NSFRC is using Key Value Observing to see your change. Now, assuming `yourObj` is your object that you mentioned above, and so when you type: `yourObj.myString = @"New String"` or `[yourObj setMyString:@"New String"]` any receivers observing that property (your NSFRC!) will be notified, because the setter is being called on your object.

Therefore, you are not receiving notifications on your "sub object" as you called it, because you are not accessing a property that is being observed by the NSFRC, rather a property of your sub object.

To trigger a notification of your sub object, you would need to call the sub object setter on your object. (ie. `[myObj setObject2:obj2]`)